# how to copy one class to another class in existing netbeans project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Netbeans environment. I want to check the existing project code with different formulas. Each class have Jframes. if i right click the jframe and click refactor finally copy the file in another name. i get below message. 
[image]

Please help me out this problem.

Comment: does this happen all the time ? or only some times ?are you sure that you didn't modify codes outside of netbeans ?

Comment: Hi fast snail, i didn't modify the code. while running the original class i get that class does n't have a main class.

Comment: and copied class work correctly. but it shows the forms seems to be corrupted

Comment: Why don't you just right click on the class and tell it to copy? Then right click on the package and tell it to paste. Do NOT refactor. After it does this you should only have to rename the class and it's constructor(s) to make it function properly. Do you still get the same error when you manually do it like this?

Comment: @user3264793 it seems to be netbeans generated code corrupted for some reason .so does your original class work ??you can delete duplicate[ refactor] class .and try again.i can't reproduce this problem

Comment: Hello blahfunk, initially i copy the specific class and created new class then pasted it  that time also i got same  message.

Comment: hi fast snail, i deleted duplicate class, but original class shows that i does not have a main class. pls help me to rectify this error

Comment: @user3264793 can you show that error from a screen shot?

Comment: sure. but i cant paste it here. i sent it to ur id

Comment: @user3264793 can you copy and paste this class to pastebin ? and when you comment add `@name` for example @fast snail  to notify to specific user

Comment: hello @fast snail, i cant find the pastebin here. but thanks for ur effort.

Comment: @Deepa13 here http://pastebin.com/